# Error when im trying add a column to a ListCtrl in wxPython(4.0.6)

Tags: python, wxpython

Im trying to add a column to a LisCtrl but i cannot

I tried to follow the documentation but i dont know what am i doing wrong

The documentation says : InsertColumn (self, col, heading, format=LIST_FORMAT_LEFT, width=LIST_AUTOSIZE)

(https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.ListCtrl.html#wx.ListCtrl.InsertColumn)

```
import wx
```

class View1(wx.Frame):
    def **init**(self,*args,**kw):
        super(View1, self).**init**(*args,**kw)

`panel = wx.Panel(self, pos=(0,0), size=(800,700))



    #TITULO
    titulo = wx.StaticText(panel,label="AGENDA DE CONTACTOS",pos=(130,1)) 

    #Creamos Sizer y le agregamos el titulo
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.Add(titulo,0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER,0)
    panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    #Texto1 X,Y
    label1 = wx.StaticText(panel,label="Nombre",pos=(70,50))
    field1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel,pos=(200,50), size=(150,20))

    #Texto2 X,Y
    label2 = wx.StaticText(panel,label="Apellido Paterno",pos=(70,90))
    field2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel,pos=(200,90), size=(150,20)) 

    #Texto3 X,Y
    label3 = wx.StaticText(panel,label="Apellido Materno",pos=(70,130))
    field3 = wx.TextCtrl(panel,pos=(200,130), size=(150,20)) 

    #Texto4 X,Y
    label4 = wx.StaticText(panel,label="Teléfono ",pos=(70,170))
    field4 = wx.TextCtrl(panel,pos=(200,170), size=(150,20)) 

    #Texto5 X,Y
    label5 = wx.StaticText(panel,label="Correo",pos=(70,210))
    field5 = wx.TextCtrl(panel,pos=(200,210), size=(150,20)) 

    #Texto6 X,Y
    label6 = wx.StaticText(panel,label="Teléfono",pos=(450,50))
    field6 = wx.TextCtrl(panel,pos=(550,50), size=(150,21)) 

    #Boton Agregar  
    botonAgregar = wx.Button(panel,label="Agregar",pos=(215,245),size=(120,22))

    #Boton eliminar  
    botonEliminar = wx.Button(panel,label="Eliminar",pos=(565,90),size=(120,22))

    #Creamos el ListCtrl para desplegar la información
    tabla = wx.ListCtrl(panel,pos=(25,350),size=(750,250), style=wx.LC_LIST)
    tabla.InsertColumn (self,0, 'NOMBRE', format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_LEFT, width=wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE)`

The result in terminal is : TypeError: ListCtrl.InsertColumn(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: argument 1 has unexpected type 'View1'
  overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'View1'

i tried remove the self parameter leaving as tabla.InsertColumn (0, 'NOMBRE', format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_LEFT, width=wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE) , but appears other error :
 wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "InReportView()" failed at /home/vagrant/wxPython-4.0.6/ext/wxWidgets/src/generic/listctrl.cpp(5196) in DoInsertColumn(): can't add column in non report mode

Comment: I think you should remove the self parameter from InsertColumn method.
table.InsertColumn(0, 'NOMBRE', format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_LEFT, ......)

Comment: i tried that, but appears other error :

    tabla.InsertColumn (0, 'NOMBRE', format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_LEFT, width=wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE)
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "InReportView()" failed at /home/vagrant/wxPython-4.0.6/ext/wxWidgets/src/generic/listctrl.cpp(5196) in DoInsertColumn(): can't add column in non report mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Attila Toth said, remove the `self` parameter. Self is automatically passed to methods in python. In this case `self` is the `wx.ListCtrl` instance, but then you pass the `View1` instance as the column number parameter.  If you're still confused about the `self` parameter [here is a pretty good explanation of it](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/)

## updated to address new question

The second error is pretty self-explanatory. Create the `ListCtrl` with the style flag `wx.LC_REPORT` instead of `wx.LC_LIST`